# How can i convert this query into a rawQuery?

Tags: sql, android, database, sqlite

I have my database query currently set up like so:

**Edit, By the way my variables (_ID, CAT_ITEM and BUDGET_AMOUNT) actualy contain exactly the same text and formatting as they are written, silly i know, but anyway that shouldn't be the problem**

```
private String[] from = {_ID, CAT_ITEM, BUDGET_AMOUNT, };
private String orderBy = _ID + " ASC";
private String whereIn = "IN_OUT='in'";

Cursor cursor = db.query(CAT_BUD_TAB, from, whereIn, null, null, null, orderBy);
```

Which does exactly what i want it to do, but i wanted to try using a rawQuery instead (just to get the hang of query statements and test it out, also i wouldn't need so many string variables).

Here's what i came up with:

```
private String incomeQuery = "SELECT _ID, CAT_ITEM, BUDGET_AMOUNT FROM CAT_BUD_TAB WHERE IN_OUT=’in’";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(incomeQuery, null);
```

However this isn't working (I get the SQLException no such column) so i'm trying to work out what the difference is, I figure there's just something wrong with my statement but no idea what. Can anyone offer me any advice? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code it looks like `_ID`, `CAT_ITEM`, `BUDGET_AMOUNT` and `CAT_BUD_TAB` are String fields.  Are their values the same as the field names?

Your single quotes also look different between the two queries.

Not related to your problem, but you will also need to add `ORDER BY _ID ASC` to the end of the sql to replicate the result order.

Comment: Right sorry i forgot to mention that the variables you mentioned above are strings but they infact contain exactly the same text and formatting (String CAT_ITEM = "CAT_ITEM"; and so on) But thanks for pointing it out i should have said something. Anyway you're right! I hadn't noticed the single qoutes looked different! (i copied the working one from a guide) Thank you for pointing it out, now if i can just work out what key to press on my keyboard it'll be problem solved :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, you have the following:

```
private String[] from = {_ID, CAT_ITEM, BUDGET_AMOUNT, };
```

If this is correct, it means that you have three *variables* _`ID`, `CAT_ITEM` and `BUDGET_AMOUNT` with the *names* of the columns in your table. The same goes for `CAT_BUD_TAB` that probably holds the name of your table.

For your raw query to be correct, it should then be written like this:

```
String incomeQuery = "SELECT " + _ID + ", " + CAT_ITEM + ", " + BUDGET_AMOUNT + " FROM " + CAT_BUD_TAB + " WHERE IN_OUT=’in’";
```

And just to have said it: this is not a nice way to compose a string. It should instead be done using a `StringBuilder`. I just did it like this here for simplicity.

Comment: Oh thanks i should have mentioned this but the three variables are actually exactly the same as their contents! (i know, silly.) but that means that that's probably not problem. Thanks for the response anyway! And i'll look into StringBuilder

Comment: @Holly: not at all silly to have variables with the same value as their name - just be sure to actually use the variable all the time ;) Back to your question: you should then post a bit more of the error. The `SQLException no such column` probably says a bit more (hopefully which column it doesn't find).

Comment: @Holly: and one more thing you could do. Try to just write `SELECT * FROM...` just to see that you actually manage to perform a raw query. If that works, you can then go back to try fetching only the columns you need.

Comment: Thanks for helping me find the problem! But it turns out i was just using an apostrophe instead of a single quote, doh,  Thank you anyway :)